SwiftData does not persist changes using 2 model contexts in iOS18
I've got a simplified app demoing the issue. It works perfectly fine in iOS 17, but in the latest betas of iOS 18, there's something not on.
I'm using 2 model contexts, one is created in UI through @Query macro, the second one is by using model actor. According to Apple, I can have as many model contexts as I want, but if I try to modify data using those two models, only UI model context persists the changes. Changes made by model actor context are after ~20 seconds rolled back.
I've got a demo app to play with you can get it here
Scenario:

Create a note (add title and review id)
Go to Reviews view (there is shown review id and how many nots have this id attached)
Edit the note and modify the review id and save.
Go to Reviews view - you can see the changes you made
Got to Notes view and then go back to Reviews view after about 20 seconds.
Changes are not persisted.

Note.swift
@Model
final public class Note
{
    var title: String = ""
    var reviewId: String = ""

    init( _ title: String, _ reviewId: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.reviewId = reviewId
    }
}

EditNoteView.swift
@MainActor
struct EditNoteView: View
{
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Environment(\.dataModel) private var dataModel

    private var note: Note

    @State private var title: String
    @State private var reviewId: String

    var body: some View {

        ...

        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                Button {
                    Task {
                        await updateNote()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Save")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    init (note: Note) {
        self.note = note
        _title = State(initialValue: note.title)
        _reviewId = State(initialValue: note.reviewId)
    }

    @MainActor
    func updateNote() async
    {
        // The following line does work in iOS 18 - all updates happen in one model context
        //await dataModel.updateNote(title: title, reviewId: reviewId, persistentModelId: note.persistentModelID)

        // The following line does NOT work in iOS 18 - note is updated in 2 different model contexts - only main actor saves data
        await dataModel.updateReviewId(reviewId: reviewId, persistentModelId: note.persistentModelID)
        note.title = title // if this line is commented it works too

        dismiss()
    }
}

DataModelActor.swift
@ModelActor
final public actor DataModelActor : DataModel
{
    ...

    public func updateNote(title: String, reviewId: String, persistentModelId: PersistentIdentifier) {
        guard let note = modelContext.model(for: persistentModelId) as? Note else {
            return
        }
        note.title = title
        note.reviewId = reviewId
        try? self.modelContext.save()
    }

    public func updateReviewId(reviewId: String, persistentModelId: PersistentIdentifier) {
        guard let note = modelContext.model(for: persistentModelId) as? Note else {
            return
        }
        note.reviewId = reviewId
        try? self.modelContext.save()
    }
}

I expect that the code should work like it works on iOS17.

Please file that feedback at http://feedbackassistant.apple.com.

Do you have this issue still in the released iOS 18? I have an issue where I insert a model in a Share Extension but the model never appears in my App. It works on iOS 17 devices but not iOS 18 devices.

Unfortunately the issue still exists :( I’ve found another SwiftData issue on iOS 18 (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/764229#764229021) This is not a framework you can rely on in professional applications.
